# How to add a legend for each line type with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I would like to add a legend specifying the difference between the two linetype I've used. I'm pretty sure it's something very basic to do but I cant make it work despite trying different things...

You'll find below an reprex of my code.

```
x<-c(1:10)
y<-c(runif(10,min=50,max=100))
z<-c(runif(10,min=50,max=100))
group=c("A","A","B","C","B","C","C","B","A","B")
session=c(rep("S1",5),rep("S2",5))

test<-data.frame(x=x, Serie1=y,Serie2=z,group=group,session=session)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(test)+
  geom_line(aes(x=x,y=Serie1,group=group,col=group,pch=group),linetype=1)+
  geom_line(aes(x=x,y=Serie2,group=group,col=group),linetype=2)+
  labs(x="x axis",y="yaxis")+
  facet_grid(.~session)
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: shape
```

[image]
Does anyone have an idea on how I could add a legend for the linetype to specify that serie1 is represented with the solid line and serie2 with the dashed line?
Also, does anyone know why there is the following warning when I run the previous code : "Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: shape" ? 
Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a legend for something, it needs to be inside the `aes()`. Move `linetype=` into the `aes()` and you can give the lines names when you so that. Also the error message about shape was coming from the `pch=` which isn't a valid parameter for lines.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(test)+
  geom_line(aes(x=x,y=Serie1,group=group,col=group,linetype="series1"))+
  geom_line(aes(x=x,y=Serie2,group=group,col=group,linetype="series2"))+
  labs(x="x axis",y="yaxis")+
  facet_grid(.~session)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I needed! I had tried this before but I had an error message (Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale) but I guess it was caused by linetype=2 . Thanks again!